# Некорректное отображение верстки

Tags: css3, html5, вёрстка

Есть сайт [ссылка](http://wezom.webazex.com/lesson2.php). На нем хэдэр высотой в `height: 60px;` соответственно блок-родитель `<div class="all-container"></div>` сдвинут при помощи `top: 60px;`.
Проблема состоит в том что если какому-то элементу, для которого all-container будет родительским - задать `margin-top: Npx;` или  `margin-botom: Npx;` то двигается родительский элемент, а не тот к которому применен margin. Как можно решить данную проблему? padding - не выход.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.lesson-header {
  top: 0;
}
.all-container {
  margin-top: 60px;
  top: 0;
}
.content{
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

Тогда все работает.

Comment: Сейчас я добавил padding к all-container поэтому за его счет и работает. Но это временное решение.